# How to scroll file browser of internal memory triggered by Cordova mfilechooser plugin

Tags: android, cordova, appium

I wan to chose a file in cordova andoird app which is using Cordova mfilechooser plugin to broswe files. I used the following Appium code to that. But scroll is not happening.

```
AndroidElement list = (AndroidElement) driver
   .findElement(By.id("android:id/list"));
MobileElement list_group = list.findElement(
     MobileBy.AndroidUIAutomator(
     "(new UiScrollable(new UiSelector)).scrollIntoView(" +
    "new UiSelector.text(\"importSample\"));"
));
list_group.getLocation();
list_group.click();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The below code will work for scrolling the page in browser screen.

We can use Dimension class in selenium: import org.openqa.selenium.Dimension;

CODE:

```
Dimension size = driver.manage().window().getSize();
int x = size.getWidth() / 2;
int startY = (int) (size.getHeight() * 0.10);
int endY = (int) (size.getHeight() * 0.90);
TouchAction ta = new TouchAction(driver);
ta.press(x, endY).waitAction(Duration.ofSeconds(1)).moveTo(x, startY).release();
ta.perform();
```